# Given $Pr(C|M)$ and $Pr(C|F)$, find $Pr(M|C)$

Tags: probability

My question: The probability that a male is colourblind is 0.05 while the probability that a female is colourblindis 0.0025. If there is an equal number of males and females in a population, find the probability that a personselected at random from the population is ***male given that the person is colourblind.***

Textbook's answer: $0.9524$

I have managed to solve this with a two-way table.

$Pr(M|C) = \frac {0.05}{0.0525}$

However I am unable to solve the problem using $Pr(M|C) = Pr(M ∩ C)/Pr(C)$

$Pr(C) = Pr(C|M) + Pr(C|F)$

$Pr(C) = 0.0525$

By I am confused of why $Pr(M ∩ C) = Pr(M)$

Intuitively, I know that we are selecting a man from the sample; however formula-vise, it is bit counterintuitive how the probability of selecting a man and a colourblind person is equal to the probability of selecting a man.

It would be appreciated, if you could correct my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your confusion arises from couple arithmetic errors that come before it.

I assumed that you have obtained that $Pr(M|C) = \frac{0.05}{0.0525}$, and calculated that $Pr(C) = 0.0525$. Thus, by the correct definition of conditional probability $Pr(M|C) = \frac{Pr(M \cap C)}{Pr(C)}$, you are trying to reason that $Pr(M \cap C) = 0.05$, and wonder why it is equal to $Pr(M)$.

The more obvious error that occurred is that $Pr(M)$ is not $0.05$, but actually $0.5$.

The more subtle error that lead to the confusion is that $Pr(C)$ is actually *not* $0.0525$. You have effectively double counted both the male and female who are colour blind in your population by writing $Pr(C) = Pr(C|M) + Pr(C|F)$. By the law of total probability, it should be

$$Pr(C) = Pr(C|M)Pr(M) + Pr(C|F)Pr(F) = 0.05 \cdot 0.5 + 0.0025 \cdot 0.5 = 0.02625.$$

You can then calculate $Pr(M \cap C)$ using the given $Pr(C|M)$ and $Pr(M)$, and verify the fraction $\frac{Pr(M\cap C)}{Pr(C)}$ is equal to what you obtained with a two-way table.

Comment: Thanks. I think the mistake is that he wrote $Pr(C) = Pr(C|M) + Pr(C|F)$, but it should be $Pr(C) = Pr(C|M)Pr(M) + Pr(C|F)Pr(F)$.

Comment: @Michael Yes I think that's it, which in my interpretation effectively double counts the male and female. Let me make it a bit more explicit in the answer.

Comment: @B.Liu Hello thanks for answering. Okay, but why $Pr(C)≠ Pr(C|M) + Pr(C|F)$? I thought the total probability is just picking a colorblind person from men and female. How does that doubt count male and female population? Could you please also elaborate on your following statement: "You have effectively double counted both the male and female in your population".

Comment: @RahulPatel You are indeed correct that the total probability is picking a colour blind person from the male and female population, but you may have confused it with $Pr(C) = Pr(C \cap M) + Pr(C \cap F)$. By adding the two conditional probabilities directly together, you have effectively ignored the fact that only half of the population are male/female, and effectively "included" the female population into your colour-blind-given-male count, and vice versa, hence the double counting.

Comment: @RahulPatel In a slightly different view, take a numerical example. Say the population has 10000 male and 10000 female (i.e. 20000 in total). The probabilities in the original question say there are 500 male who are colour blind and 25 female who are colour blind, hence 525 in total. To calculate $Pr(C)$, you have to divide 525 with the total population of 20000. What you did in directly adding the two conditional probabilities together is effectively treating the total population as 10000. Hence, the 525 colour blindness cases now have double the leverage than they should have.

Comment: @RahulPatel I have clarified in the answer that the double counting is on those who are colour blind, not the general population.

Comment: @B.Liu Thank you very much for your time and effort. I had misunderstood the probability of selecting a colourblind person out of men population with the probability of selecting a colourblind man out of total population and vice versa for women. Once again thanks a lot.